# .NET GC specification and multiple threads

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, thread-safety

Does in a finalizer method my cleanupcode need to be thread safe? Or is the GC itself ALWAYS executing in a single thread?

@Edit: clearing: it doesn't matter **which** thread the finalizer is executed in. I need to be sure it will only be **one single** thread, i.e. the finalizer will only be called **exactly one time**?

Comment: I can tell you that the latter certainly isn't the case, but the former case is interesting...

Comment: It's not the GC that always executes in a single thread; it's the finalizers that always execute in a single thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard does not specify anything about which thread finalizers are run on.  From §10.9 (Automatic memory management):

> "For instance, C# does not require that
>   finalizers be run or that objects be
>   collected as soon as they are
>   eligible, or that finalizers be run in
>   any particular order, or on any
>   particular thread."

Comment: That's what I thought, but then, wouldn't that potentially dramatically slow down any significant finalization code, because of the need to lock/unlock?

Comment: Real implementations may always use a particular thread for finalizers, for that reason.  But you asked about the standard, which is deliberately very flexible.

Comment: From the way the GC executes the finalizer, I would expect it to be threadsafe inherently. Meaning that we should expect the GC thread to be different to the main thread. But the finalizer will only be called exactly one time. I was simply curious and wanted to make sure. thanks!

Comment: @user492238: Why do you think the finalizer can be called more than once?

Comment: I dont. But where do you know, its not?

Comment: There is no reason why the GC at some point could not have a finalizer thread for each CPU, after all sometimes the GC has a collection thread per CPU at present.

Comment: @Ian, I agree.  I don't see anywhere the standard prohibits this (though I could be mistaken).

Comment: Yeah, OK, I'll agree with that, but if they trip up that so that the two finalizer threads for a duo-core runs the same finalizer, there's not much hope that we can handle that in any meaningful way. In any case, I would very much like to know what kind of problem that user492238 wants to solve or prevent here, because I don't think there is anything related to GC or finalization, in and of itself.

Comment: @Lasse V.Karlsen: a rather complicated ressource pooling library. The memory for large (numerical) objects is taken care of for disposal in the pool. For performance reasons it is more efficient, to relay on the assumption, the finalizer is never called concurrently. Even if this feels natural, I hence could not find a reliable reference for it.

Comment: @Ian: if I am getting you right, your answer is "yes" (it needs to be thread safe)?